# How to sort array by 'includes'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a user object with an ID, name pass, etc.. and also a Vacations array of objects(vacations) each of them has 'followers' with all the user **id's** that follows('likes') the vacation.

Like this:

```
vacations: [{name:'Germany', Price:200 ,followers:['fsdas7213nasd'], follows:1 }]
```

Now, I want to sort the vacations to show first the vacations that includes the user id. how would I do that?

Comment: please add unsorted and sorted data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? @NinaScholz

Comment: `vacations` s just one of the key from the object.Share the entire array of object and also the expected result

Comment: for sorting data, you need an array of values or objects. your given data does not look like that. please add your data for sorting. (and the wanted result.) and what you have tried.

Comment: @QuikLeaner sample input data for answers to use, expected result, and what you have tried so far

Comment: You need to add the code attempts you've made to your question as [mcve]s. Here's [how to ask good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's only one value in the `vacations` array; nothing to sort. Also, please do some research and show the result of that research.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It was just an example, the array is actually empty right now, im pulling it off API that i've built.

Comment: @Andy I haven't made any attempts yet, that is why I asked at the end of my question 'How would I do that?' If I had an idea i wouldn't be asking it here.

Comment: @QuikLeaner Go to your code. And do `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` and copy the text from console and paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vacations.sort((a, b) => b.followers.includes(userID) - a.followers.includes(userID));
```

Both `includes` calls will result in a boolean, which will be casted to false -> 0, true -> 1 due to the subtraction. Therefore the whole expression results in

- -1 (a first) if userID is included in a's followers only
- 1 (b first) if it is only in b's
- 0 (keep order) if it exists in both / none.